# "Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable" prevents overriding empty init

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a situation where I'm trying to override `NSError` to provide me an instance of an error I'm going to be re-using a lot.

My code was working until I updated Xcode and converted to Swift 2.

```
public class NAUnexpectedResponseTypeError: NSError {
    public convenience init() {
        let messasge = "The object fetched by AFNetworking was not of an expected type."
        self.init(
            domain: "MyDomain",
            code: 6782,
            userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: messasge]
        )
    }
}
```

The compiler says `Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable`. I was able to hack around it by doing this:

```
public class NAUnexpectedResponseTypeError: NSError {
    public class func error() -> NSError {
        let message = "The object fetched by AFNetworking was not of an expected type."
        return NAUnexpectedResponseTypeError(
            domain: "MyDomain",
            code: 6782,
            userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message]
        )
    }
}
```

So, my question is:

1. Is there a way to add an empty `init` method in a situation like this?
2. If yes to 1, is that a bad idea for some reason?
3. Is my workaround with the class method an appropriate way to mitigate this problem?

EDIT:

I came up with another workaround that I like better than the workaround with the class method. I'm still not happy that I can't override the empty `init` method though.

```
public class NAUnexpectedResponseTypeError: NSError {
    public convenience init(message: String?) {
        var errorMessage: String
        if let message = message {
            errorMessage = message
        } else {
            errorMessage = "The object fetched by AFNetworking was not of an expected type."
        }
        self.init(
            domain: "MyDomain",
            code: 6782,
            userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorMessage]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you adding more code to your class besides what's shown here? Because I'm wondering why a subclass is even necessary.

Comment: @TomHarrington Would you suggest something like an extension for NSError?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `NSError` is immutable, there's no reason to create multiple instances of the same data. Just create a single, constant, instance:

```
let NAUnexpectedResponseTypeError = NSError(domain: "MyDomain",
    code: 6782,
    userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "The object fetched by AFNetworking was not of an expected type."]
)
```

If you have a situation that isn't constant, then it is almost always better to extend rather than subclass `NSError`. For example:

```
extension NSError {
    class func MyError(code code:code, message: String) -> NSError {
        return NSError(domain: "MyDomain", 
                       code: code,
                       userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message])
   }
}
```

This kind of extension (as a category) has a long history in ObjC, and is a good pattern to bring to Swift (if you can't easily use `enum` ErrorTypes, which are even better Swift).

In many cases I find it even easier just to have a top-level function for this, rather than extending `NSError`. For example:

```
private func makeError(code code:code, message: String) -> NSError {
    return NSError(domain: "MyDomain", 
                   code: code,
                   userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message])
}
```

(Personally I use these kinds of functions all the time in Swift when I have to use `NSError`. In ObjC, I typically used categories on `NSError`. Not sure why I changed, but it feels more natural.)

Comment: Very helpful and thorough. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can't override the empty init, it's marked as unavailable so you're not supposed to be able to do anything with it.

You do have another workaround though

```
public class NAUnexpectedResponseTypeError: NSError {

    public convenience init(message: String = "The object fetched by AFNetworking was not of an expected type.") {
            self.init(
                domain: "MyDomain",
                code: 6782,
                userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: message]
        )
    }
}
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.

Since you're using swift 2.0, why don't you make your instance conform to error type instead of subclassing NSError ? It would be cleaner and more idiomatic.